Merge intervals based on condition
This is the classical approach to merge intervals:
def merge(intervals: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
    result = []
    intervals.sort()        
    prev_interval = intervals[0]

    for curr_interval in intervals[1:]:
        if prev_interval[1] >= curr_interval[0]:  # Check if they overlap
            prev_interval = [prev_interval[0], max(curr_interval[1], prev_interval[1])]
        else:
            result.append(prev_interval)
            prev_interval = curr_interval
    
    result.append(prev_interval)
    return result

I'd like to modify this solution to merge the intervals if 'end' of any interval + 1 is equal to 'start' of any interval in the list.

Ex.1: intervals = [[1,2], [3,4]] ==> [[1,4]]
Ex.2: intervals = [[1,5], [6,9]] ==> [[1,9]]
Ex.3: intervals = [[1,5], [14, 17], [6,9], [10,13]] ==> [[1,17]]
Ex.4: intervals = [[1,5], [14, 17], [6,9], [10,13], [4,7], [8,12]] ==> [[1,17], [4,12]]

I cannot build on top of my current solution, because I'm not assured that intervals that have potential to overlap will be adjacent in the sorted form of given intervals list. An inefficient solution would be iterating over each pair combination in the list, and if they overlap, removing them from the list and pushing their merge into the result.
Can you help me to create this function in the most optimal way possible?

Would any working solution be better than none? "the most optimal way" may demand proof that people aren't willing to spend time on providing.

What should happen if there are multiple ways one interval could merge with another? For example, [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 6]], should the result be [[1, 4], [3, 6]] or [[1, 6], [3, 4]]? What makes one of these ways more "optimal" than another?

Unless you need to handle enormous lists, don't worry about getting an optimal solution.

I'm not sure that your concern about adjacency is really a problem. Can you give an example of an input list with overlaps where they don't become adjacent when it's doing the merges?

@Barmar Their Ex.4: [1,5] and [6,9] won't be adjacent, will be separated by [4,7].

@nocomment But after you merge [1, 5] and [4, 7] you'll have [1, 7], and [6, 9] will be after that, so it will merge those as well.

@Barmar [1, 5] and [4, 7] don't get merged. See the desired output for that example and the merging rule.

@TedLyngmo I can already visualize the brute-force approach (take each interval pair, if they are suitable to merge, remove them from the list and add their merge into the result, after finishing one iteration, which is O(n^2), repeat the process on the merged list until nothing left to merge) ends up with worse than O(n^2), which is quite inefficient. I am asking this for a bit brainstorming towards the optimal solution frankly.

@kaya3 Good point. In that case, it is better to prioritize the interval with lower end value. Optimality is not about the output result for me, but is the performance of the algorithm.

Is it better to greedily prioritize the interval with the lower end value, even if the result will be an interval with a higher end value? E.g. for [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 6], [5, 100]] is [[1, 100], [3, 6]] or [[1, 6], [3, 100]] a better result?

@nocomment Why won't they be merged? After the list is sorted, you'll have [[1, 5], [4, 7], [6, 9], ...]. When prev_interval == [1, 5] and curr_interval == [4, 7] the criteria prev_interval[1] >= curr_interval[0] will be true and they'll be merged.

@Barmar That's the code for what they called "classical" merging. Not for their merging criterion that they're asking about. [1,5] and [4,7]  don't get merged because 5+1 doesn't equal 4.

@nocomment I thought this was going to be in addition to the classical merging. So they just have to change prev_interval[1] >= curr_interval[0] to prev_interval[1]+1 >= curr_interval[0].

@Barmar Then their expected result would be [[1,17]], not [[1,17], [4,12]].

@nocomment I didn't notice that. It seems weird that they no longer want to merge the overlaps just because they're merging adjacents.

Providing that, like in your examples, there are no duplicating starts or ends in the input, you can achieve a linear time complexity by converting the intervals to two dicts, one that maps starts to ends and one that maps ends to starts. Iteratively find mergeable intervals both forwards and backwards from a starting interval until all intervals are accounted for:
def merge(intervals):
    result = []
    start_end = dict(intervals)
    end_start = dict(map(reversed, intervals))
    while start_end:
        start, end = start_end.popitem()
        while (next_end := start_end.pop(end + 1, None)) is not None:
            end = next_end
        while (next_start := end_start.get(start - 1)) is not None:
            del start_end[start := next_start]
        result.append([start, end])
    return result

so that:
for intervals in (
    [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    [[1, 5], [6, 9]],
    [[6, 9], [1, 5], [14, 17], [10, 13]],
    [[10, 13], [1, 5], [14, 17], [4, 7], [8, 12], [6, 9]]
):
    print(f'{intervals} => {merge(intervals)}')

outputs:
[[1, 2], [3, 4]] => [[1, 4]]
[[1, 5], [6, 9]] => [[1, 9]]
[[6, 9], [1, 5], [14, 17], [10, 13]] => [[1, 17]]
[[10, 13], [1, 5], [14, 17], [4, 7], [8, 12], [6, 9]] => [[1, 17], [4, 12]]

Demo here

One-direction version.

@StefanPochmann These are quite clever solutions, appreciated! What if we had duplicate start or end values? How can we handle such cases?
Let's say [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 6]] should be either merged into [[1, 4], [3, 6]], or into [[1, 6], [3, 4]], both accepted (or maybe first-comes-first-merged)?
